# Most efficient way to aggregate tabular data meeting certain conditions in Python in O(1) time?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a table with a bunch of data in long format (each row has one data point). For instance, let's say we have a table of people's SAT scores, with columns for state, city, school, gender, race, and person. My goal is to find a way to easily pull out and average data points corresponding to certain groupings of the data.

For instance, if I were to want to average the SAT scores associated with males in Texas, or white females in NYC. What's the best way to do this in Python (I suppose it's similar to `tapply` in R)? Boolean indexing on a `Pandas` data structure? Is this done in `O(1)` time? Obviously the dumbest possible way would be to crawl through row by row, check if each row meets the conditions, and collect the numbers that do, but I can't help but think there's a better way than this; I don't this to become unnecessarily slow as my datasets get bigger.

Comment: If you haven't computed any aggregates yet, you of course have to look at all rows to be able to tell which ones are matching your criteria.  If you want to do many look-ups of this kind with partially overlapping criteria, you might be able to preprocess the data in a way that the individual look-ups can be sped up, but you need to look at each row at least once at some point.

Comment: pandas can do [grouping and split-apply-combine](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) types of operations (better than R imo). This seems to be exactly what you're looking for. Start here and maybe ask another question If you have an example that you need help with.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Sven: couldn't the lookup be achieved in O(1) time with some sort of hashing system, where all the "label" columns constitute keys and the data of interest (here, SAT scores) constitute values? Or is this unfeasible, and O(n) is realistically the best one could hope for here?

EDIT: On perusal, it looks like pbreach's link describes just that. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You have the right idea, ask another question if your code doesn't behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in O(1) time.

This problem has more than one complexity associated with it. I can think of three:  Prepossessing, insertion, and lookup.

You could do this in O(nlog(n)) preproccessing  +  O(log(n)) lookup time, and O(log(n)) insertion as follows:

```
 from collections import deque
 datatable = collections.deque(your_data_table)
 column_names = ['col1', 'col2'...etc]
```

Keep an extra data structure updated which always has a list of pointers to rows of your main table sorted by each column. I.E if you have a data table with 6 columns, you will need 6 sorted arrays with values that point to row numbers of your main table. This extra structure should take up the same amount of memory as your original data table.

```
overhead_structure = {}
for column, column_name in zip( column_names, table):
    row_indexes, sorted_column_values = sort(column)
    overhead_structure[column_name] = (sorted_column_values, row_indexes)
```

With the new extra overhead of a sorted meta-data -> you can search for rows that satisfy your criterion with binary search on each of the rows upon which you have conditions.

```
from bisect import bisect_left
overhead_index = bisect_left(overhead_structure[column_name], 1, lo,hi)
real_index = overhead_structure[column_name][overhead_index][1]
```

Also with the new overhead of sorted meta-data, each time you add another row to your main table, you will have to cram in the pointer to it in your new meta-data sorts. So you will have to figure out where that row belongs in each column sort.

```
for column_name in column_names:
    overhead_index = bisect_left(overhead_structure[column_name],1, lo,hi)
    real_index = overhead_structure[column_name][overhead_index]
    overhead_structure[column_name].insert(overhead_index, (new_item, real_index))

datatable.append(new_item)
```

This is the fastest way I can think of off the top of my head.. I suspect there is a more robust and better way to do this though, because it is EXACTLY what SQL databases have to deal with under the hood with SELECT statements, and years of smart people working hard have made those queries fairly optimized.

EDIT:

Using arbitrary data types will give you headaches with insertion, because the native array has fixed lengths. Using a doubly linked list datatype could make insertion time go down, and create even MORE memory overhead, but keep the other complexities where I estimated them. I wrote some sudo-code with python '''deque'''